# python - django: type object 'Owner' has no attribute 'get_by_user'

Tags: python, django

I have those models:

### models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import admin

class Owner(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    account = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=6, max_digits=20)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70,blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.name,self.last_name)

    @staticmethod
    def get_by_user(request):
        try:
            ow = Owner.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.pk)
            return ow
        except:
            return None

    class Meta:
        db_table            = u'backend_owner'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Owners'

class Portfolio(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.name,self.owner)
```

---

### admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from backend.models import *
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

# Define an inline admin descriptor for Employee model
# which acts a bit like a singleton
class OwnerInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Owner
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'owner'

# Define a new User admin
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (OwnerInline, )

class PortfolioAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Portfolio
    list_display    = ['name']

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(PortfolioAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        ow = Owner.get_by_user(request)
        if not ow is None and ow.count():
            return qs
        return qs


# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
admin.site.register(Owner)
admin.site.register(Portfolio, PortfolioAdmin)
```

---

Owners is OneToOneField to admin.user => extend class. I want to get a portfolios list for user, so I'm trying to override the queryset.

Error says: type object 'Owner' has no attribute 'get_by_user'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see what's causing that error, but note that your approach is totally unnecessary. All relationships, including OneToOneFields, add a reverse accessor to the related model. So your method can be completely replaced by a simple call to `request.user.owner`.

(Also, even if you did end up needing some kind of extra functionality, methods that operate on querysets should really go on the Manager class, not as static or class methods on the Model.)

Comment: Finally I've called the owner from the admin: